# native-speaker's errors?

Tags: errors

I suspect that the following opening paragraph in an email is not written by an educated native speaker of English.

> It has come to my attention that there has been several times whereby students had specifically phoned or went in personally to request for leave, but their notice was not indicated in the name sheet. Is it now the current protocol not to indicate their notice of leave in the name sheet?

"Times whereby", "in the name sheet", "request for leave", and "had phoned in" look suspicious. Am I correct in seeing these constructions as likely indicators that the text was written by a non-native speaker?

Comment: Not all native speakers speak or write well.

Comment: Besides looking suspicious, what, specifically do you see as a problem with those phrases?

Comment: What @Robusto said. Reading between the lines, so to speak, I think most likely the text *was* written by a native speaker. Someone who's not well-versed in formal written styles, but is so preoccupied with the futile attempt to sound as if they *are* that they've accidentally included a really basic error in a verb form *(...there **have** been several...)*.

Comment: What about 'IN the name sheets"? The misused preposition is like an ESL error, isnt it?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with “indicated in the name sheet” (assuming _name sheet_ is what they call whatever exactly it is that’s being referred to here). _In_ or _on_ are both perfectly natural prepositions to use here. (I’ve edited your question a bit to make it less opinionated, though I fear it may still be thought of as being primarily opinion-based.)

Comment: I think this was quite likely written by a native speaker: "there has been several times" is a mistake native speakers are prone to make, and the "in" in "had phoned or went in personally" is fine—the "in" doesn't have to apply to "phoned" (although it should be *had gone* in).

Comment: has been -> have been.    times whereby-> times when.    had..went in -> have gone in.  now...the current  (redundant).  I'd bet $10,000   a native speaker wrote it.

Comment: It's all a matter of opinion, obviously. But I think it's quite surprising that *competent* native speakers can feel relatively confident in identifying *another native speaker* attempting to emulate a register they're not very familiar with. The "hidden clues" in language use can be subtle indeed.

Comment: The only thing that really stands out to me is "there has been ... requests" and this sort of verb number problem is very common among native speakers.  It usually shows up in "there is" constructions or with compound subjects ("the x and y is" where x and y are related but distinct items).  Hell, I even say things like "there's three buttons missing" in casual speech.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the origin of the speaker. However, correcting some glaring errors in the sentence may assist you in reaching a conclusion:

> There **have** been several times **when** students have phoned or
>   **gone** in personally to request **[omit for]** leave, but their **notices were** not indicated in the name sheet. Is it now the current protocol not to indicate their **notices** of leave in the
>   name sheet?

The expression *name sheet* may be correct depending on the organizational context. I lived in India for a few years and was exposed to many non-native speakers. In my opinion, "request for leave" is a telltale sign of a non-native British English speaker.

Comment: I disagree. Native speakers quite naturally say *I put in a request for leave*, and a "minimally-articulate" person is quite capable of inappropriately substituting ***request*** for ***ask*** when trying to sound formal/authoritative, so that one's hardly relevant to the question as posed. Your point about ***wherein*** is simply mistaken. That would only apply in contexts referencing *periods of time having a **duration*** - but in this context the referent is ***occasions*** (of no meaningful duration), so it doesn't really work even apart from the fact that it's "stilted, starchy".

Comment: Would like to make clear: 'request for leave' is normal (to make a request for leave) as a noun but as a verb TopDog is right.

Comment: @Avon: The "non-idiomatic" aspect is simply that native speakers normally *ask **for** [what they want]*, but they ***request it*** (no preposition) if they're using the more formal verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers another valid but clunkier fix would be "submit a request for leave". "request for leave" on it's own acts as a noun, and doesn't fit into the list of "phoned" and "gone" which are both used as verbs.

Comment: Yes, there are certainly many aspects of the text that could be "fixed/improved" with relatively minimal changes, and it's at least *possible* the clumsy original phrasing could be generated by a (relatively advanced) NNS. But I still think that taking everything into account, it looks more like the work of a (relatively inarticulate) NS unsuccessfully trying to use a register they're not familiar with. Would a NNS include the vacuously irrelevant word ***specifically*** in such a context, for example? I kinda doubt that, but it seems just what an inarticulate NS might do to sound "erudite".